# SPSS to R: Distinguish between discrete missing values and system missing values

Tags: r, spss, missing-data

I have datasets in SPSS that I'm pulling into R. Short of going through all these datasets and recoding user entered discrete missing values, how can I distinguish these from system missing values in R?

As an example, users who selected N/A - don't use - were coded as a discrete missing value (-99). In SPSS, these values are distinguished from system / "true" missing values. When I bring the dataset in R, the values coded -99 as missing are simply "NA."

How would I go about distinguishing between these in R? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Read the file with this parameter

```
na.strings = c(-99,'NA')
```

Comment: that codes them as NA so they are not distinguishable from system missing values. Found the solution though thanks! use.missings = FALSE